# How do i construct a regex for the hostnames

Tags: regex

host names can be long/fqdn:

```
cs25-admin.nmtg.company.com 
cs25-admin.nms.company.com
```

or short:

```
cs25-xyz23
```

but should not match

```
11.22:33:44:55-66
```

I wrote this: `/.*-.*(nmtg)*|.*(\.nms)/`

but fails for the last one 11.22:33:44:55-66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^[^:]+$/`, although I suspect I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks that worked, how do i filter certain words? `/^[^:admin]+$/` doesnt seem to work

Comment: It would be simpler to have a regex that matches anything with `:` and `admin`, etc and negate the result.